# How does shovel (<<) operator work in Ruby Hashes?

Tags: ruby, hash

I was going through [Ruby Koans tutorial series](http://rubykoans.com/), when I came upon this in `about_hashes.rb`:

```
def test_default_value_is_the_same_object
  hash = Hash.new([])

  hash[:one] << "uno"
  hash[:two] << "dos"

  assert_equal ["uno", "dos"], hash[:one]
  assert_equal ["uno", "dos"], hash[:two]
  assert_equal ["uno", "dos"], hash[:three]

  assert_equal true, hash[:one].object_id == hash[:two].object_id
end
```

The values in `assert_equals`, is actually what the tutorial expected. But I couldn't understand how there is a difference between using `<<` operator and `=` operator?

My expectation was that:

- `hash[:one]` would be `["uno"]`
- `hash[:two]` would be `["dos"]`
- `hash[:three]` would be `[]`

Can someone please explain why my expectation was wrong?

Comment: Funny, that's exactly what I expected. Then, mountains were again merely mountains.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

When you're doing `hash = Hash.new([])` you are creating a Hash whose default value is the exact same Array instance for all keys. So whenever you are accessing a key that doesn't exist, you get back the very same Array.

```
h = Hash.new([])
h[:foo].object_id # => 12215540
h[:bar].object_id # => 12215540
```

If you want one array per key, you have to use the block syntax of `Hash.new`:

```
h = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
h[:foo].object_id # => 7791280
h[:bar].object_id # => 7790760
```

**Edit:** Also see what Gazler has to say with regard to the `#<<` method and on what object you are actually calling it.

Comment: Got it thanks. So, the original empty array is an object that is stored as a default value. And we keep getting back that original object instead of a `nil`. Neat! Thanks to both answers (by you and @Gazler), upvoting both, but accepting this.

Answer (score 71):

You have mixed up the way this works a bit.  First off, a Hash doesn't have a `<<` method, that method in your example exists on the array.

The reason your code is not erroring is because you are passing a default value to your hash via the constructor.  http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-new

```
hash = Hash.new([])
```

This means that if a key does not exist, then it will return an array.  If you run the following code:

```
hash = {}
hash[:one] << "uno"
```

Then you will get an undefined method error.

So in your example, what is actually happening is:

```
hash = Hash.new([])

hash[:one] << "uno"   #hash[:one] does not exist so return an array and push "uno"
hash[:two] << "dos"   #hash[:two] does not exist, so return the array ["uno"] and push "dos"
```

The reason it does not return an array with one element each time as you may expect, is because it stores a reference to the value that you pass through to the constructor.  Meaning that each time an element is pushed, it modifies the initial array.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much more clear explanation. Thanks

Comment: I know this is years old but for this answer is far clearer to a beginner than the accepted answer.

Comment: I also know this is years old -))