# RubyKoans - Confusing hash example

Tags: ruby, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How does shovel (<<) operator work in Ruby Hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343680/how-does-shovel-operator-work-in-ruby-hashes)

I'm making my way through the [RubyKoans](https://web.archive.org/web/20210117032044/http://www.rubykoans.com/), and one of the examples regarding hashes is really confusing me. The example is in the `about_hashes.rb` file. Here is the code that is confusing me:

```
hash = Hash.new([])

hash[:one] << "uno"
hash[:two] << "dos"

assert_equal __, hash[:one]
```

*For those unfamiliar with RubyKoans, you are supposed to fill in the correct value for the double-underscore.*

In this example, I see that the variable named `hash` is using the `Hash` object constructor, which replaces the default value of `nil` with an empty `Array`. Then, two items are added to `hash`, each with one array element, using the `<<` Ruby operator. I would expect that `hash[:one]` would return an array of value `["uno"]`, but Ruby is telling me that it actually is `["uno", "dos"]`. What gives?

Comment: If you have two questions, you should ask two questions. That way they can both be answered, they can both be googled, they can both be found by other people who have the same question. Currently, your question about `:foobar` is buried in a question with a title about `Hash`es, that is tagged with `hash`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Hash` constructor is using a reference to the same array as the default value, so all hash values will actually be initialized to the same array by default until you use the `[]=` operator on a hash key (e.g., `hash[:one] = some_new_object`). This is why you see both strings in the array.

According to [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343737/129655), you need to use a block form for the Hash constructor. That block will be executed for every new hash key:

```
hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

As for the colon-prefixed tokens, those are literals for what are called *symbols*. Symbols are much like strings, but have a few crucial differences. One is that the same symbol value will always reference the same object in memory (which is not necessarily true of strings). Symbols have other characteristics that make them perform slightly better than constant strings. Symbols are otherwise very much like string literals.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same result without using the block syntax? This Ruby behavior is really weird.