# Rubykoans about_hashes.rb

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does shovel (<<) operator work in Ruby Hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343680/how-does-shovel-operator-work-in-ruby-hashes)

Struggling to find documentation on why this works the way it does:

```
1 def test_default_value_is_the_same_object
2    hash = Hash.new([])
3
4    hash[:one] << "uno"
5    hash[:two] << "dos"
6
7    assert_equal ["uno", "dos"], hash[:one]
8    assert_equal ["uno", "dos"], hash[:two]
9    assert_equal ["uno", "dos"], hash[:three]
10
11   assert_equal true, hash[:one].object_id == hash[:two].object_id
12 end
```

I would have thought that "uno" would be assigned to the hash[:one] key and hash[:two] would receive "dos".  I've corrected it so that it passes the tests, however I don't know why it is operating this way.  Could someone point out what I'm missing or direct me to relevant documentation on this particular aspect.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's no `:one` key, as well as `:two` key. Trying to access value under any of these keys returns a default value, i.e. array, the one you've initialized the `Hash` with in the `Hash.new([])`.

Answer (score 0):

> I would have thought that "uno" would be assigned to the hash[:one] key and hash[:two] would receive "dos"

They are not assigned (`=`), they are pushed (`<<`) into `hash[:one]`.

Comment: I just found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343680/how-does-shovel-operator-work-in-ruby-hashes that explained it all, thank you!